# Distribute IOS app in-house without register devices

Tags: ios, mdm

I have enterprise apple account and i tried to submit the application but apple rejected because app is not for public use so they suggested to use business account.
Its long process to register and get organization verified so i tried upload ipa and manifest file on my server and download it in IOS device though link but it requires device registration to run in IOS device.

CONCLUSION :

> I want to distribute app to all users through my website without
> register devices.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your best approach is to use a custom app. This can be distributed by an MDM or by providing redemption codes to users

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for suggestion!
Apple said we have to use Apple Business Manager option but i want other way.
Please let me know if have any idea

Comment: Your only two options are an enterprise program membership or a custom app with your existing company developer program and Apple Business Manager. This second approach is much easier to manager and faster to organise than an enterprise program.